# Concurrent invalidations of the same object in Cloudfront via Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I have a problem with concurrent creations of Cloudfront invalidations from AWS Lambda for the same object.

I have set up a Lambda handler to be triggered by specific S3 objects creations and removals, in order to perform invalidation of cached versions on my Cloudfront distribution. This is the function code, written using Python. The code does not detect if an invalidation is currently in progress:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
import time

import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(
   retries = {
      'max_attempts': 6,
      'mode': 'standard'
   }
)

cloudfront = boto3.client('cloudfront', config=config)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for items in event["Records"]:
        path = "/" + items["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    print(path)
    invalidation = cloudfront.create_invalidation(DistributionId='xxxxx',
        InvalidationBatch={
            'Paths': {
                'Quantity': 1,
                'Items': [path]
        },
        'CallerReference': str(time.time())
    })
```

I wonder how I would tell the function to only trigger when there is no invalidation status of InProgress for that same object?

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how I would tell the function to only trigger when there is no invalidation status of InProgress for that same object?

The function will always trigger. There is no way to tell it to not trigger based on something happening in CloudFront.

However, you could add some logic in the function to only send an invalidation request to CloudFront if one isn't already running for that path. To do this you would [list the current invalidations](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.list_invalidations), and then [get the details of each invalidation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.get_invalidation) to see if it has the same path.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the required pieces!